# Regulated and semi-regulated functions with values in Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the following definitions, we assumed that $(X,\left\|\cdot\right\|)$ is a Banach space.

**Definition 1.** $f:[a,b]\to X$ is *regulated* if it has one-sided limits at every point of $[a,b]$, i.e. for every $c\in [a,b)$ there is a value $f(c+)\in X$ such that
$$\lim_{t\to c^+}\left\|f(t)-f(c+)\right\|=0$$
and if for every $c\in (a,b]$ there is a value $f(c-)\in X$ such that
$$\lim_{t\to c^-}\left\|f(t)-f(c-)\right\|=0.$$

**Definition 2.** $f:[a,b]\to X$ is *semi-regulated* if for every real number $\alpha$ satisfying $|\alpha|\le 1$, the function $F_\alpha:[a,b]\to X$ defined by $F_\alpha(t)=\alpha f(t)$ is regulated.

**Remark.** It follows from the two definitions that *regulated $\Rightarrow$ semi-regulated.*

Now, I would to see that the converse of the preceding remark is false. If it is false, can you please help me by providing an example of a semi-regulated function which is not regulated.

Comment: Since $\lvert 1 \rvert \leqslant 1$, from $F_1 = f$ follows that semi-regulated $\Rightarrow$ regulated. (Any $\alpha \neq 0$ would do.)

Comment: Why are you sorry? I don't see a reason for that.

Comment: I mean, I was ashamed with my question and I have to sorry myself. You noted my question smartly.

Comment: Pfft, you read something, and it wasn't directly clear to you. So you asked for clarification. Nothing to be ashamed of, that's (part of) what the site's for.

Comment: Many thanks to you sir.God bless...